# myview = nil but there are still a view on superview

Tags: ios

i put on a view named myView on superview, after that, i code myView = nil, but not remove from superview, and there are still a view like myView appeared in superview, please help me and tell me why.

Comment: you have to call myView.removeFromSuperview()

Comment: thank you, but i know how to remove, and what confuse me is that why i had make myView = nil, there are still a view on superview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is why `myView = nil` doesn't remove the view from superview ( and so, why it doesn't deallocate it ).

This is quite simple, when you do `viewA addSubview:viewB` you create a reference from `viewA` to `viewB`.

So when you do `viewB = nil`, you still have a pointer from `viewA` to `viewB` so `ARC` doesn't release the view.

That's why you should call `[viewB removeFromSuperview]` to delete the pointer.

Comment: you are welcome :) can you mark the question as resolved ? :)

Comment: im sorry ,could you tell me how to make the question as resolved? i m a newbee

Comment: you should be able to mark my answer as "it solved my problem"

Answer (score 0):

Please remove your view from super view before making it nil using `[myView removeFromSuperView];`

Comment: thank you, but i know how to remove, and what confuse me is that why i had make myView = nil, there are still a view on superview

Comment: Sometimes super view doesn't lay out if you make subview nil

Comment: it's not sometime, it never layout when i make subview nil, and how to make   superview layout forcibly

Comment: myView is a variable which was taking reference of a view. the view is added to superview and now superview acts as owner as myView is its child view now. When you assign nil to myView (myView = nil), myView has no value (Literal) now, i.e. it contains reference to nothing. Lets take a scenario. a = 5. print a, its display 5. Now assign null value to a like a = 0 or a = nil. but it still print 5. How we can say why value 5 is still printing. Hope you understand my friend.